# DB2 - Read Write Locks

Tags: concurrency, db2, locking

I am working on a web application which involves inventory management. My application uses DB2 as the database.

1) In my application, there is a module which just inserts the records. This can happen at anytime since the records are entered by customers.

2) And there is another stand-alone module which reads and updates the records entered. This module never Inserts records. It just updates existing records. This module is scheduled so it will run once an hour.
My question is, the second module can read and update the records without an issue if the first module is inserting a record at the same time? I am not referring to the record just being entered at the time but the other records in the table that needs processing. **( Bottom line is when first module inserts data, can my second module read and update data in separate rows of the same table at the same time ? )**

I am very new to DB2 and heard about the locking in DB2. That is why I raised this question.

Adding the following information about my application. Both modules are written in java. Second module is a spring boot application. Operating system is windows.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series (OS/400), or Linux/Unix/Windows.   You should also know the __isolation level__ of your connection(s) and/or SELECT statements because the isolation level influences the locking, as well as . Also add which programming language you are using, and the locking strategy, and the locking configuration of the database and instance.  When properly configured, inserts can be concurrent with select/update *as long as you know what you are doing*, and as long as your code can properly handle lock-waits, or retries after conflicts.

Comment: @mao thank you for the input. I updated question. I am not very familiar with locking strategy, and the locking configuration of the database and instance.I will ask out DBA member regarding this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's cross-posted on [DBA.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269284/db2-read-write-locks)